# ModelAndView not returning model to the JSP in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, jsp-tags

I am trying to display the object in a jsp page that are returned via a controller, but I am not seeing the object in the jsp. Below is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/{groupName}", menthod = {RequestMethod.Get, RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView groupAlphaHandler(@PathVariable("groupName") String groupName, HttpServletRequest request) {

    ArryList<GroupAlphaInfoVO> groupAlphaInfoVO = groupAlphaService.loadGroupAlphaSearchResult(groupName);
    //view name "group-alpha"     
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("group-alpha");
    mav.addObject("groupAlphaInfoVO", groupAlphaInfoVO);
    mav.addObject("pageTitle", "Group Alpha");
    //added debug point here and made sure groupAlphaInfoVO is not null (it has around 1000 records)
    return mav;
    }
```

Here is my jsp page ***group-alpha.jsp***:

```html
<html>
<head>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Group Alpha</title>
</head>
<body>
        ${pageTitle}<!-- this is getting displayed on jsp-->
 ${groupAlphaInfoVO}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perhaps you need to use `forEach` in your jsp

Comment: `<c:forEach items="${groupAlphaInfoVO}" var="dataList"> ${dataList.groupName}</c:forEach>`....this did not work

Comment: check whether your list in jsp is empty `<c:if test="${empty groupAlphaInfoVO}">the List is empty</c:if>`

Comment: `<c:if test="{groupAlphaInfoVO == null}" <h2> the list is empty</h2></c:if>` when i did this, it displays the list is empty, but i dont know why

Comment: please don't hate me for this, the problem was from controller i was passing groupAlphaInfoVo and in jsp i was using groupAlphaInfoVO

Comment: check list is empty or not in controller

Comment: its not empty, the problem was with the case sensitive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174896/discussion-between-abhi-and-john-joe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you are making a silly mistake in the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/{groupName}", menthod = {RequestMethod.Get, RequestMethod.POST})
```

There is a spelling mistake. It's not `**menthod**` it's `**method**` 
And I think there is no need for using `RequestMethod.POST`

Another mistake is `mav.addObject("groupAlphaInfoVO", groupAlphaInfoVO);` with this code you are putting list of object. And in the JSP page you didn't do any operation on the list. To print that list you should write `<c:forEach>....</c:forEach>` code. For example

```
<c:forEach var="results" items="${groupAlphaInfoVO}">
       <c:out value="${results.userid}"></c:out>
       <c:out value="${results.password}"></c:out>
       <c:out value="${results.role}"></c:out>
       <c:out value="${results.contact}"></c:out>
       <c:out value="${results.mentor}"></c:out>
       <c:out value="${results.group}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

For using   you need to add JSTL dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And add `<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>` at the top of your jsp page.

Comment: As you mentioned, `method=RequestMethod.GET` is enough. And the spelling mistake. What showing in jsp page?

Comment: @varman please check my edited answer. Let me know if I miss anything !

Answer (score 2):

You need this `isELIgnored="false"`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"%>  //here
```

Comment: if that is the case then `${pageTitle}` should also not work, any way i added this `isELIgnored="false"` but still it doesn't work

Comment: Why your head tag contain <%@ page language=...%>. That should be on the top of the jsp.

Comment: I updated it to the top of jsp, still not getting the result

Comment: You need to read this page : http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/jsp/activating-and-deactivating-el-evaluation-in-jsp

Comment: yeah, I understood that, but when I use `${pageTitle}` it is working, so I think there is some other issue which I am not able to figure it out

Comment: Okay check answer, please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174849/discussion-between-abhi-and-quang-dat-pham).